# Why intermediate relation created in postgresql query can not be referenced in where clause filter?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, sql-delete

I am trying to remove duplicate data from a table in postgres. In my table, there's not primary key.

```
postgres=# select * from customer_temp;
 id | firstname |  country  | phonenumber
----+-----------+-----------+-------------
  1 | Sachin    | India     |        3454
  2 | Viru      | India     |        3454
  3 | Saurav    | India     |        3454
  4 | Ponting   | Australia |        3454
  5 | Warne     | Australia |        3454
  7 | Be;;      | England   |        3454
  8 | Cook      | England   |        3454
  8 | Cook      | England   |        3454
  8 | Cook      | England   |        3454
(9 rows)
```

I am using following query to delete duplicate records.

```
delete from customer_temp temp 
using (select  out1.id, out1.firstname 
       from customer_temp out1 
       where (select count(out2.id) 
              from customer_temp out2 
              where out1.firstname=out2.firstname group by out2.firstname
              ) > 1
       ) temp1 
where temp.id in (select id 
                  from temp1 
                  where id not in(select id 
                                  from temp1 
                                  LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0));
```

But I am getting following error:-

```
ERROR:  relation "temp1" does not exist
LINE 1: ...name) > 1) temp1 where temp.id in (select id from temp1 wher...
```

Although relation temp1 is created as part of `using`, then why I can't use them in where clause filter.

As per [How Select SQL gets executed](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/what-is-the-order-of-execution-of-an-sql-query), FROM is executed first and the result of row is available to next stages of query execution. Then, why temp1 is not available to subqueries in `where` section.

Comment: Maybe start formatting your source code.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . Assuming that `id` uniquely identifies each row, this is a simple way to write the logic:

```
delete from customer_temp
    where id not in (select min(ct2.id)
                     from customer_temp ct2
                     where ct2.id is not null
                     group by ct2.firstname, ct2.country, ct2.phonenumber
                    );
```

I do note that I'm using `not in` with a subquery.  I do usually warn against this (although this is safe because of the `where`).  You can do something similar with `exists` or using `>` and a correlated subquery.

EDIT:

If `id` is not unique, then it is a really bad name for a column.  But apart from that, you can use `oid`:

```
delete from customer_temp
    where oid not in (select min(oid)
                      from customer_temp ct2
                      group by ct2.firstname, ct2.country, ct2.phonenumber
                    );
```

[This is a built-in identifier.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-oid.html)

However, the best approach is probably just to rebuild the table:

```
create table customer_temp_temp as
    select distinct on (firstname, country, phone_number) t.*
    from customer_temp t
    order by firstname, country, phone_number;
```

Comment: What will happen, if table doesn't have primary key ? Will the query change in that case ?